# How to make checkbox tri-state?

Tags: css, angular, checkbox, angular5

**Technology Used :**  Angular 5

**Scenario :**

- I have a tree view with a checkbox. Whenever data is loaded onto the page, based on the property I am making checkbox checked or unchecked.

**Todo :**

- Whenever property is false I want to add a cross mark in checkbox by default.

Below is my code which will render tree view with the checkbox.

```
<tree-root #tree [options]="options" [nodes]="nodes">
    <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index">
        <input (change)="check(node, !node.data.checked)"
               type="checkbox"
               [indeterminate]="node.data.indeterminate"
               [checked]="node.data.checked" class="css-checkbox">
        {{ node.data.name }}
</ng-template>
</tree-root>
```

In the above code snippet whenever **`node.data.checked`** is true then I am making checkbox checked by default. Whenever **`node.data.checked`** comes false I want to display cross mark in the checkbox.

I have searched over the net but did not get any use full links.

Can someone help me to make this work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi I am using Angular 5. the example you shared is in Angular 1.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice. I retracted the flag.

Comment: Thats okay! Are you able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger `[checked]`, the **[`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)** pseudo-class will be applied. You can use this to target checkboxes which have been checked (either manually or programmatically).

Adding a cross in the checkbox is a little harder, as you cannot add one to an `input[type=checkbox]` itself. To get around this, you can hide the checkbox itself (with `display: none`), and make use of a `<label>` which is associated with the checkbox, bound by the label's `for` attribute. By using `for`, when clicking on the label you'll simulate clicking on the checkbox itself.

The label can be styled to **look** like the original checkbox, and also offers extra flexibility, allowing for things like a `background-image` (which can be used to show the cross).

Assuming your `<label>` elements come directly after your `<input>` elements, you can target them with the **[adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)**, with selectors such as `input + label`. This can be chained with the `:checked` pseudo-class to style the labels for the checkboxes that are checked: `input:checked + label`.

Here's an example:

```css
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
  background-position: 0 -15px;
}

.css-label {
  background-image: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/lite-x-red.png);
}
```

```html
<input id="one" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="one" class="css-label"></label>

<input id="two" class="css-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="two" class="css-label"></label>
```

While a checkbox can only ever have **two** states (either checked or unchecked), what **is** possible with Angular is to update the associated **class** of the element. If you want a tick (or similar) as well, this is your best bet.

Simply create one class for when the value is truthy, one for when it is falsy, and apply the relevant class to the label depending on the value. The positive class would have a check `background-image`, and the negative class would have a  cross. The 'default' would show up empty, as is in the above example.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am following https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/blob/master/example/cli/src/app/checkboxes/checkboxes.component.ts. On page load whenever node.data.checked is true then i want to make it check else add cross mark. Now by default cross mark is displaying. May i know how to fix it?

Comment: Hi I want to conditionally add the class. If the property node.data.checked is true then checked else i want to add class css-label! how can i do this?